# Let (X,d) a metric space. Show that a function is continuous

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

Let (X,d) a metric space. Show that the function y↦d(x,y) is continuous. Please help me, I don't know where to start.

Comment: Start off by writing the definitions.

Answer (score 1):

$d(x,y) \leq d(x,y')+d(y,y')$ and $d(x,y') \leq d(x,y)+d(y,y')$. Combine these to get $|d(x,y)-d(x,y')| \leq d(y,y')$.

Comment: and then how can prove the continuity?